# CSS3 Smooth Cross Browser Grayscale Image

Tags: css

Can some one let me know how I can modify the following code to  make a smooth fading transition in all browsers?

```
img.grayscale {
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
}
img.grayscale.disabled {
filter: none;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

right now it is changing the color scale at once in Firefox, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is no pure CSS3 solution to this per the "Browser Wars" where some browser support some features and some don't. But, for modern browsers (Chrome, Safari 4+, Firefox 11+?, Opera 12+? and IE 10+) you can use CSS3. Here's some code:

```
img.grayscale {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter .3s ease-in; /* chrome & safari */
    -moz-transition: filter .3s ease-in; /* firefox and other gecko-based */
    -ms-transition: filter .3s ease-in; /* ie 10+ */
    -o-transition: filter .3s ease-in; /* opera */
    transition: filter .3s ease-in; /* w3 (future standard) */
}
```

However, there are cross-browser remedies, just not using CSS purely.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the easiest way to do this cross-browser is still just keeping 2 copies of the image (one greyscale) and transitioning the opacity.

Using that same technique (2 overlapped images - fading the top one out), you can perhaps build something where the top and bottom are the same image, but the top has all the browser-specific filters on it.